# including external javascript in Gatsby using Helmet

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I have this code in the index.js of layout folder:

```
<StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <>
        <Helmet
          title={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
          meta={[
            {name: 'description', content: 'Sample'},
            {name: 'keywords', content: 'sample, something'},
          ]}
          script={[
            {"src": "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js", "type": "text/javascript"}
          ]}
        >
          <html lang="en" />

        </Helmet>
        <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
        <div>
          {children}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )}
  />
```

However the Bootstrap.js file is not included in the project...
I tried various syntax things and also restarted the project, nothing works so far.

Comment: Do you have index.html under public directory?

Comment: yes. But thats a generated file

Comment: Not sure how it behaves with react-helmet, but in other cases if you want to add some external scripts you can add it there, and whatever you add there will be available in the build index.html file

Answer (score 2):

Helmet supports all valid head tags like title, base, meta, link, noscript, style, including script tag. So you can do it like this :

```
<Helmet>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
</Helmet>
```